# Python Replace Letter With ( _ )

Tags: python, string, random

i am recently creating a Guessword Game and I'm having a trouble to make the chosen world from a list to come as underscores, and then a letter at a time needs to be inserted and if correct will be replaced with the _, any help pls ? i recently am at this point but don't know how to continue :P [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVpT2.png)

Comment: Please provide example of trouble in code, for instance code snippet which doesn't work, expected result, actual result so it would be easier to assist you.

Comment: Please post your code ***here*** instead of an image. If someone wants help you and debug your code, I think he doesn't want type your code by hands himself.

Answer (score 2):

You can construct a new string based on the letters not guessed:

```
>>> guessed = ['e', 'o']
>>> word = 'hello'
>>> ''.join(c if c in guessed else '_' for c in word)
'_e__o'
```

Then you can test if complete by comparing the words:

```
>>> guessed = ['h', 'e', 'l', 'o']
>>> word = 'hello'
>>> word == ''.join(c if c in guessed else '_' for c in word)
True
```

Comment: You just have to count the "_".

Comment: Yes, there are many ways - you don't even have to count, just `not in` would be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to create a list and use a `for` loop for the detection of a letter in order to insert the character in the list:

```
s = 'hello'
secretWord = ['_' for i in s]

for ind, char in enumerate(s):
    if char =='e':
        secretWord[ind] = char

print(secretWord)            # ['_', 'e', '_', '_', '_']

print(''.join(secretWord))   # _e___
```

Comment: You can write: 'secret = "_"*len(s), no?'

Comment: Yes, but in this case, you migth to use another structure of data, like bytearray for the replacement of a character or to modify str to list

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want convert a word to underscores? Then create another string object which has the same length underscores. For example:

```
>>> cW = 'Hello'
>>> ''.join('_' for i in s)
'_____'

>>> len(s) == len(''.join('_' for i in cW))
True
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `replace()` method on strings to replace specific letters. For example:

```
'this is a test'.replace('i','_')
```

will return

```
th_s _s a test
```

To replace a whole word, just create a string of the same length, which only consists of `_` like @Kevin Guan suggested:

```
''.join('_' for letter in word)
```